# Angular 2 - with ngFor, is it possible to update values without rebuilding the dom?

Tags: angular

I have a component 'bar' inside ngFor. I want to update its width with animation starting from the previous value to new one.

html :

```
<div *ngFor="let station of stations" class="station">
    <bar [perc]="station.perc" class="bar"></bar>
</div>
```

ParentComponent :

```
ngOnInit(){
    setInterval(() => this.updateData(), 10000);
  }

  updateData(){
    const url = 'http://....';
    this.http.get(url)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {

        this.stations = data;

      });
  }
```

BarComponent

```
export class BarComponent {

  @Input() perc;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef){}

  ngOnChanges(changes: any): void {
    let perc = changes.perc.currentValue;
    TweenMax.to(this.element.nativeElement, 1, { width: perc + '%' });
  }

}
```

But on each updateData() it looks like ngFor recreates the dom and BarComponent is constructed again. So even if 'station.perc' is the same,  ngOnChanges() is fired.

And the transition keeps on restarting from 0 instead of starting from the previous value...

I probably miss a crucial point here but whats the clean workaround?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I guess you should use `trackBy` option to customize the default tracking algorithm the `ngFor` directive:

**view**

```
<div *ngFor="let station of stations; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn" class="station">
  <bar [perc]="station.perc" class="bar"></bar>
</div>
```

**component**

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return index;
}
```

or a bit better use unique id:

```
trackByFn(index, station) {
  return station.id;
}
```

See more details about the trackBy here:

- https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby

Hope **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/pE0QFjEmT86ucUqRp2fQ?p=preview)** will also help you.

Comment: Cool, you saved me, bro

Comment: Just update the link to - https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby