# Updating view with data from web socket - Angular 5

Tags: angular, websocket

I have a page that receives an array of data on page load and displays it with an `*ngFor` directive. There is also a connection made to a Web Socket to receive updated data. In this example its a timetable for boat trips. My problem is that I am unsure how to update the page load data with the new data from the WS. So far I have this code:

**timeTableService.service.ts** - service to get the initial data on page load

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Injectable()
export class TimeTableService {

    constructor(
        private apiService: ApiService,
    ) { }

    getInitialTimes() {
        return this.apiService.get('/timetable/')
    }
}
```

**liveTimeTableService.service.ts** - service to connect handle web socket connection using [this library](https://github.com/ohjames/rxjs-websockets)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { QueueingSubject } from 'queueing-subject'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import websocketConnect from 'rxjs-websockets'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share'

@Injectable()
export class LiveTimeTableService {
    private inputStream: QueueingSubject<any>
    public messages: Observable<any>

    public connect() {
        this.messages = websocketConnect(
            'ws://www.timetables.com:8080',
            this.inputStream = new QueueingSubject<string>() 
        ).messages.share()
    }
    public send(message: string):void {
        this.inputStream.next(message)
    }
}
```

**timeTable.component.ts** - component to display the timetable

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TimeTableService, LiveTimeTableService } from './shared';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-time-table',
    templateUrl: './time-table.component.html',
})

export class TimeTableComponent implements OnInit {
    private timeTable: any;
    private socketSubscription: Subscription

    constructor(
        private timeTableService: TimeTableService,
        private liveTimeTableService: LiveTimeTableService,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.liveTimeTableService.connect();
        this.liveTimeTableService.send('SUBSCRIBE times')

        // subscribe to any message updates
        this.socketSubscription = this.liveTimeTableService.messages
            .subscribe((timesUpdate) => {
                this.timeTable = timesUpdate;
        })

        // get the time table data on page load
        this.timeTableService.getInitialTimes()
            .subscribe((timeTable) => {
                this.timeTable = timeTable
        })
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.socketSubscription.unsubscribe()
    }
}
```

**HTML template**

```
<div *ngFor="let boat of timeTable">
    {{ boat.name }}
    <span *ngFor="let time of boat.times">{{time}}</span>
</ldiv>
```

And the **data** looks like this

[Page load data](https://gist.github.com/fogofogo/1873c58ed6efdb89375de9ed73b3d8a9)

[WS Message data](https://gist.github.com/fogofogo/3ed7927efd558e581174e701b66677ac) (contains minor updates like time and status):

The problem is that `this.timeTable` is reset every time a new message comes from the WS and the entire `*ngFor` directive runs again and rebuilds the dom. What I wanted to do was update any ‘time’ expression in the `*ngFor` with the new values from the WS message, and then apply a css class to notify users of a change:

[image]

Any advice or suggestions how I can active this would be greatly appreciated. And apologies for the very long post!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the trackBy option, like in this answer:

[Angular 2 - with ngFor, is it possible to update values without rebuilding the dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979831/angular-2-with-ngfor-is-it-possible-to-update-values-without-rebuilding-the-d)

So, your code will be something like:

**View:**

```
<div *ngFor="let boat of timeTable; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
    {{ boat.name }}
    <span *ngFor="let time of boat.times">{{time}}</span>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return index;
}
```

As reference, you should use: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby